# How to resolve the duplicate column name error in Room Db migration

Tags: android, android-room

I added the below code for adding a column to the `SithluBody` table when migration.

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE SithaluBody ADD COLUMN has_thumb INTEGER NOT NULL 
        DEFAULT 0");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE SithaluBody ADD COLUMN reacts TEXT");
    }
};
```

but I got the error ==>

> Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
> duplicate column name: has_thumb (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR).
> How can I fix it? please help me.

Comment: Do you have `has_thumb` column? It seems already exist in your `SithaluBody` table.

Comment: As my knowledge, "has_thumb" is new column. that error come from firebase crash. And also its affected to small number of users. Others work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the two problems:

1. You have the `has_thumb` column added.
2. You installed an older version in your device/emulator that had that column name, and now that you are trying to do this migration, it's having a conflict.

In case of the second option, try to uninstall or clear the data of you app in the device/emulator and try to install the app again.

Comment: How can we handle this instead of uninstalling it? Can't we check if the column name exists?

Comment: That's a way to prevent you as a user from re-installing the app yes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe somehow (in your testing, forgot to update the BD version), you have an old version 3 with `has_thumb` column, then after that update the BD version to 4 and add the migration, then this issue happens.

The fix is, before running the migration script, check if the column exists or not first

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        if (doesColumnExistInTable(database, "SithaluBody", "has_thumb")) {
          return;
        }
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE SithaluBody ADD COLUMN has_thumb INTEGER NOT NULL 
        DEFAULT 0");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE SithaluBody ADD COLUMN reacts TEXT");
    }
};

 private boolean isColumnExist(SupportSQLiteDatabase db, String tableName, String columnToCheck) {
        try (Cursor cursor = db.query("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT 0", null)) {
            return cursor.getColumnIndex(columnToCheck) != -1;
        } catch (Exception Exp) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```